# How to easy create combobox in vba and work with it?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I would like to create ComboBoxes in my cells.
I've figured out how to create such a thing in a specific cell:

```
Set curCombo = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        With curCombo
            .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 2
            .ControlFormat.AddItem "yes", 1
            .ControlFormat.AddItem "no", 2
        End With
```

I will have a lot of ComboBoxes in my Sheet. So now, I have a problem with how to find ComboBox which I am interested in, and get the value, having the row and column of this Combobox.
What's more, I would like to have this in the cell. It means that if I would like to remove the entire column, all combo boxes will be removed too.

I will appreciate all the answers because I have this problem for a long time and can't figure it out.

Comment: Don't know your requirement, but would using simple *Data Validation" an option?

Comment: Check if this solves your issue: https://access-excel.tips/excel-data-validation-combo-box/

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. It will be much better in my case. I didn't know about 'Data Validation'. Thanks a lot!